# How to scale docker based services in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-service-fabric

What is the best way to scale docker based application services in azure. In AWS I know we can use container service.  Currently I am using Cloud Service on azure,  which enables easy scaling. There is also Service Fabric which looks better than cloud service. But when I use docker how can I scale them to multiple VMs?

Comment: You are confusing managed or server-less technologies like Service Fabric with server technologies like Docker. Service Fabric is like AWS Lambda - you don't care where it runs, it's the cloud provider's job to do this for you. Most likely both run on top of containers. Besides *why* do you want to use Docker when the *cloud provider* already handles scaling of your *managed* service? There are no VMs involved that you'd have to scale. You only have to increase the IO/processing units available to your service and the provider will take care of scaling it

Comment: EC2 Container service works similar to Azure's Cloud Service. But It takes docker image as source, and it is scalable like Cloud Service. I am just trying to find if we have docker + scalable to multiple vm on Azure. Also I just quoted Service Fabric because it look like will replace Cloud Service. I am not planning to use Fabric Service as it required minimum of 5 VMs. So the question is "When I use docker how can I scale them to multiple VMs on Azure easily?"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Azure VM Scale Sets, this allows easy integration with Azure autoscale. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-vm-scale-sets-public-preview/

A couple of additional things worth tracking..

1) The upcoming preview of Azure Container Service, see announcement: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-container-service-now-and-the-future/

2) The Mesos Cluster with Marathon and Swarm solution in Azure Quickstart Templates: [https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mesos-swarm-marathon](https://github.com/rgardler/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/acs/acs-mesos-full-template)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have just announced the Azure Container Service which provides Mesos or Swarm orchestration

Launch blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-container-service-preview/
Service home page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/acs-intro/

Answer (score 0):

For scaling plain Docker containers in Azure you can use ACS (Azure Container Service) with Docker Swarm or Mesos DC/OS underneath.

Another option is to use Azure Service Fabric which its version for Linux uses Docker, too. In regards SF for Windows, it will have Docker pretty soon using Windows Docker containers. 
Service Fabric goes further (it is not just orchestration of containers for scaling) as it provides application platform and prescriptive frameworks like Stateful services, Reliable Collections and Actor Framework.